# ng-click change parent class

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs

I'm attempting to build a simple slide out menu, I have it working fine using the menu button.

```
<div class="menu-button" ng-click="show_menu = !show_menu"></div>

<div class="side-menu" ng-class="{true: 'show_menu'}[show_menu]">
        <div class="filters-generic filter-{{filter.filter_type}}" ng-repeat="filter in filters" ng-click="show_menu = !show_menu;filterby(filter.filter_type)">{{filter.filter_type}}</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.side-menu {
  left: -25%;
  position: absolute;
  transition: all 0.2s linear 0s;
  width: 25%;
  background: #000;
}

.side-menu.show_menu {
    left:0%;
}
```

When I press the `menu-button` div it works fine (i.e it adds the class), however I also want to be able to close the menu when an item inside it is picked, I have tried the above but nothing is happening.

I thought originally it had to do with the fact that its calling another function too, but I even removed that and there's still the same issue. Am I misunderstanding how `ng-click` works?

Comment: I have a work around with the line `$scope.show_menu = false;` in the `filterby()` function. This seems to work but still doesnt really answer the question , for learning purposes I would still like to know why it didnt work in the above code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ng-repeat` directive create new scope - child to scope where your `show_menu` exists. So by clicking on menu item (some filter I think) you is changing `show_menu` in that child scope actually. But `ng-class` watches for `show_menu` in parent scope, which was not changed.

For more information read here: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes

**PS**: You can write `ng-class`:

```
<div class="side-menu" ng-class="{ 'show_menu': show_menu }">
```

which much more concise and clearly, I think.

Comment: Thanks, I did a quick google after your explanation I found out you can affect the parent scope by including `$parent` , so the solution is `$parent.show_menu = !$parent.show_menu;`